# Find and replace with Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

i have the lines below, and would like to find a specific word (the one between the *) FYI - the '*' is not there, i added to highlight the interesting word

```
neighbor 10.1.1.1 route-map *wred900_NWK* out
neighbor 10.1.1.1 route-map *grn_NWK* out
neighbor 10.1.1.1 route-map *blu_NWK* out
```

i am not sure how to write the regex to find these. the only common thing after and before is "route-map" and "out"

Comment: Is that the only place you will have '*' character ?

Comment: My guess is that there's no actual * character and this was just for demonstration...?

Comment: I strongly advise you to edit your question and improve it by adding some more details and example of what you already tried and did not work.

Comment: it seems it is always 4th word so you can `line.split(' ')[3]` and you don't need `regex` for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split upon space(s) and take the 4th column:

```
>>> s = "neighbor 10.1.1.1 route-map wred900_NWK out"
>>> re.split(r"\s+", s)[3]
'wred900_NWK'
```

Comment: thanks Mateen it works

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy to solve. Find on google a regular expression tester.
The part you are interested in can be matched by something like this:
“ \ *[a-zA-Z0-9_] \ * out“

Then you just load your file and use the function “findall”.
This might be helpful:
https://www.guru99.com/python-regular-expressions-complete-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

text = """neighbor 10.1.1.1 route-map *wred900_NWK* out
neighbor 10.1.1.1 route-map *grn_NWK* out
neighbor 10.1.1.1 route-map *blu_NWK* out"""

result = re.findall(r"[*].*?[*]", text)

print(result)
```

Comment: the * is just for indication, i just left it there to highlight what word i want to find. they dont actually exist in the actual file